# locating child element by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup and I am praticing with little tasks. Here I try to get the "previous" link in this [site](https://www.xkcd.com/). The html is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n2LB.png)

My code is

```
import requests, bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.xkcd.com/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find('div', id="comic")
url2 = result.find('ul', class_='comicNav').find('a', rel='prev').find('href')
```

But it shows NoneType.. I have read some posts about the child elements in html, and I tried some different things. But it still does not work.. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `prev` link.find ul tag and then find a tag. Try below code.

```
import requests, bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.xkcd.com/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
url2 = soup.find('ul', class_='comicNav').find('a',rel='prev')['href']
print(url2)
```

**Output**:

```
/2254/
```

Answer (score 1):

Tou could use a CSS Selector instead.

```
import requests, bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.xkcd.com/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.select('.comicNav a[rel~="prev"]')[0]
print(result)
```

if you want just the href change

```
result = soup.select('.comicNav a[rel~="prev"]')[0]["href"]
```